# Send and receive files via lan

Tags: files, lan, kali

So I got an Kali linux machine and a Ubuntu machine, I want to send files from Kali to Ubuntu via lan if it is posible i wanna do it with any native program 
Hope someone can help me ^^

Comment: `scp` is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use scp, the documentation for this can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles), an example command might be

```
scp -r /home/user/helloworld.txt user@MACHINE.IP.ADDRESS:/home/user/
```

If you are using SCP outside of your home directory you may need to prefix the command with `sudo` to obtain proper permissions to transfer the file.

Hope this helps!

**edit**

You may be asked about

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.2.15 (192.168.2.15)' can't betablished.
ECDSA key fingerprint is ***some long number (fingerprint) ***. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Each host has a key pair and you should check the fingerprint when connecting to ensure you're not being MITMed. (Shout out @GNP - Thanks)

Comment: Why do you need `sudo`?

Comment: it works succesfully, but  some of the files im sending are corrupted I don't know why but I need to repair it so if you know any program to repair corrupted images will be welcome ^^

Comment: Ask another question to receive a better answer, data recovery is no small subject I recently used a program called foremost which had some success recovering data from a corrupt hard drive but im no expert

Comment: "`the certificate being used is self signed `" ssh keys are not certificates. Each host has a key pair and you should check the fingerprint when connecting to ensure you're not being MITMed. It has nothing to do with trusting the server, it's about veryfing the server you connect to is the server you intended to connect to.

Comment: Thanks for the incite i will re-write my answer to suite